# How does the Squeeze Theorem prove the following?

Tags: real-analysis

We have a non-empty set $S\,{\in}\,\mathbb{R}$ and a real number ${\xi}$. Distance between $S$ and ${\xi}$, or in another words ${inf_{x{\in}S}|{\xi}-x|}=0$.

I already know that $|{\xi}-x_n|<\frac{1}{n}$. Using the squeeze theorem and the fact that $\lim_{{n\to ∞}}\frac{1}{n}=0$, we can deduce that $\lim_{{n\to ∞}}|{\xi}-x_n| = 0$ as well.

And now I want to use this to prove that $lim_{n\to ∞}x_n={\xi}$. How? I really don't know what should I do at all.

Comment: What is $n$? You don't define distance in terms of $n$...

Comment: Do you really mean what you write? Two real numbers that are at zero distance are, in fact, the same number.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that you are given a sequence of points $x_n\in S$ with $|\xi-x_n|<\frac1n$ and are asked to prove that $x_n\to\xi$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |\xi - x_n| = 0 \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N : ||\xi - x_n| - 0| < \varepsilon$$
Now note that
$$ ||\xi - x_n| - 0| = ||\xi - x_n|| = |\xi - x_n| = |x_n - \xi|$$
So in particular
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N : |x_n -\xi| < \varepsilon \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \xi$$
This is however an extremely roundabout way of proving what you wish. Instead we could've done the following. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Now we have
$$ \forall n \geq N : |x_n - \xi| < \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$$
Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary the above holds for all $\varepsilon$. So we have
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \xi$$